# Complex analysis - Möbius transformation

Tags: complex-analysis

Discuss the image of the circle $|z-2|=1$ and its interior under the following transformations,

$$f(z) = z+6i$$

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z}$$

$$f(z) = \frac{1}{z-2}$$

For the first one, I have $\{w : |w-2-6i| \leq 1 \}$

Second one, $\{w: |w-\frac 2 3| \leq \frac 1 3\}$

Am I doing this correctly, and how would I go about doing the third one?

Comment: As the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first two answers look fine, apart from the fact that the inside of $|z-2|=1$ gets mapped to the outside of the circle $|w-\frac 2 3| = \frac 1 3$, rather than the inside. To see this, just consider what happens to points very close to 2.

The simplest way to do the third one is to note that if $$w = \frac{1}{z-2}$$

then

$$z-2 = \frac{1}{w}$$

so then you can replace $z-2$ by $1/w$ in the equation of your circle:

$$|\frac1w| = 1$$ which gives the circle

$$|w| = 1.$$